# Byte array to string decode java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, decode

I have a code like this:

```
@Override
public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers,
        byte[] responseBody) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String response = new String(responseBody);

    text.setText(response+"aa");

}
```

`Textview` is like this: `[B@4104dc30aa` is it byte array, if it how can I convert to normal text?

Comment: Note that the `toString` for a byte array (`[B@4104dc30aa`) is simply the array symbol `[` followed by `B` for byte, `@`, and the array's hash value -- not a helpful dump of the array for diagnostic purposes.  What you need to know is the encoding of the byte array (assuming it's character data at all).  One would hope it's UTF8, but could be others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String response = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
text.setText(response);
System.out.println("text set: " + text.getText().toString());
```

That might help.

Comment: Isn't the value returned from `getText` already a String?  Is there any point in doing `toString` on it?

Comment: @HotLicks No. Added that just out of habit. :)

Comment: To be picky, `getText` returns a `CharSequence`.